# In what sense is Syringammina single-celled?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane

In what sense is *Syringammina* single-celled? For example, if it's true that all cells have membranes (is it?), then how do you identify its membrane? Or does *unicellular* simply mean that it has only one lipid bilayer (presuming --- since I don't know one way or the other --- that the crucial ingredient of any cell membrane is a lipid bilayer (is it?))

I'm not a biologist, so please excuse my possibly annoying question.